# Elements in `Reap` and `Sow`

Tags: sow-reap

Can someone help explain it to me:

1. How does here `e` come out? Why `b` disappears?

   ```
   Reap[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e]
   ```

[image]

2. How does here `4` come out?

   ```
   Reap[Sow[1, x]; Sow[2, y]; Sow[3, x]; Sow[4, y], x]
   ```

[image]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a `CompoundExpression` the last expression is the result.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Look at the `FullForm` of the expression inside `Reap`:

```
FullForm[HoldForm[Sow[a]; b; Sow[c]; Sow[d]; e]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

In this case, the `OutPut` is just `e`, the last one. Now when you include the `Reap`ing, you get things that are `Sow`n in addition to `e`. Same explanation goes for the second one.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will look it up for `CompoundExpression`.